# Fetching Text from SQL and display lines

Tags: php, sql

How do I display text 'with line' from SQL in PHP? Below is a script similar to what I have.

```
$information = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM information");
    while($new_information = mysqli_fetch_array($information)) {
        echo $new_information['information'];
    }
```

Whereas the text in 'information' is
'Hello world!

How are you doing?' - Two lines

However it display,
'Hello world! How are you doing?' - One line

How can I make it two lines?

The table and column name is the same; information.

Comment: [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) perhaps?

Comment: useless spam in answers, nl2br is enough for such a case, as mario pointed out here.

Comment: yeah... +1 to mario from my side

Comment: Thanks mario. This is what I'm looking for. Anyway, how do I '+1' for that comment? I'm somewhat new to Stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

you should give your `column name` or `index` to it with new line `<br/>` like

```
$information = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM information");
    while($new_information = mysqli_fetch_array($information)) {
        echo $information[0]."<br/>"; // as numeric  index
    }
```

OR

```
$information = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM information");
    while($new_information = mysqli_fetch_array($information)) {
        echo $information['information']."<br/>"; // as column name
    }
```